# In a race of $1km$, $A$ beats $B$ by $100m$, $B$ beats $C$ by $50m$ and $C$ beats $D $ by $40m$, by how many metres will $A $ beats $D$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a race of $1km$,

$A$ beats $B$ by $100m$,

$B$ beats $C$ by $50m$

$C$ beats $D $ by $40m$,

by how many metres will $A $ beats $D$?

Options given are $\text{a) 190m b) 10m c) 820m d) 179.2m.}$ Literally,answer look likes $190m$ but my friends say it is not $190m$.
Which one is right answer?

Please anybody explain.

Comment: Intuition: Let us look at where people are when D reaches finish line. C is faster than D, so C will be at 1040+. B will be 1090+. A will be at 1190+. Now reverse the race. For A to go back 190+ to reach finish line, since D is slow, he will cover less than 190+ and so answer should 179.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{RACE OF A WITH B}$$

Lets assume speed of $A=$ $1$ km/s

Speed of $B=0.9$ km/s as $B$ runs only $900$ m in $1$ s

$$\text{RACE OF B WITH C}$$

Time taken by $B$ to run $1$ km is $10/9$ s

Therefore $C$ runs $950$ m in $10/9$ s

Speed of $C=$ $\frac{0.95}{(10/9)}=0.855$ km/s

$$\text{RACE OF C WITH D}$$

Time taken by $C$ to run $1$ km $=1000/855$s

Speed of $D$ is $\frac{0.96}{(1000/855)}=0.8208$ km/s

Now just compare this with $A$